# how can we use combination of NSThread and NSNotification?

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading, nsnotifications

I am doing an application where images from the user are taken all together and saved in `NSMutableArray`.
As soon as even one image has been start coming, I need to upload images to server one by one `though images are taken together`

I am using `[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(uploading:) toTarget:self withObject:imagearray];` to upload images one by one. I need to show progressview to user as images are being uploaded one by one.

How do I notify after one image has been uploaded?

Or is there any other scenario that is useful for this more than NSThread+NSNotification?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sugest to use something similar to "delegate" paradigm but thinking on threads instead of objects. So the uploading thread delegates on main thread as it is the one to make user interface changes.
For example, the uploading thread can send messages for partial upload progress

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(uploadProgression:) 
        withObject:foo waitUntilDone:NO]
```

or for each complete upload finished

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(uploadDidEnd:) withObject:foo
        waitUntilDone:YES]
```

I suppose that you have not to stop uploading for updating partial progress in progessView but you need to wait when upload ends so not to duplicate uploading threads launching a new upload.

Comment: yes I am calling `[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(uploadProgression:) 
        withObject:foo waitUntilDone:NO]
` only once and on each time this selector finishes it should call `[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(uploadDidEnd:) withObject:foo
        waitUntilDone:YES]
` and again it should come back to `uploadProgtession` with continuation of arraycount

Answer (score 0):

You should use notifications in case you don't know how many listeners it is out there and you just post notification about something. In your case you probably have only one view controller, so there is no need to use notifications so just create some protocol for the delegate and implement it in your view controller. If you need to update your UI, then you should also invoke all delegate methods using `performSelectorOnMainThread`.